# php file_upload no funciona en mi sitio web

Tags: php, hosting

Yo habia creado un sitio web que en localhost me funcionaba perfectamente, y lo paso a un host, la mayoria del sitio me esta funcionando en forma correcta, pero no estoy pudiendo subir archivos con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php  include("includes/includedFiles.php");
?>
<form  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Elije la Canci贸n: <input type="file" name="file" >


<input type="submit" name="s" value="cargar" class="button">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){

$fileName=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileName_temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$upload="public_html/assests/music";
$movefile= move_uploaded_file ($fileName_temp,$upload . $fileName);

header("Location:uploadSong2.php?");

}
?>
```

En localhost cuando seleccionabas el archivo y ponias cargar, te lo cargaba y te mandaba a la direccion que dice en el header, pero ahora en el host no funciona como corresponde, no solo no lo sube sino que se queda en la misma pagina esperando y npose que puede ser

Comment: Hola, ¿revisaste que la estructura de directorios sea consistente? Suele ocurrir que al pasar de localhost a un directorio público en el servicio de hosting la estructura sea ligeramente distinta. En particular al escribir **"public_html/assests/music"** puedes estar apuntando a **"public_html/public_html/assests/music"**. Te sugiero usar `__DIR__` para apuntar al directorio en que se encuentra el script que estás ejecutando y agregar secuencias `../` para moverte y resolver la dirección hasta **assests/music**. (continua en otro comentario)

Comment: Si el script se encuentra en public_html basta hacer `$upload = __DIR__.'assests/music';` pero, si estuviera en "public_html/includes" debes hacer algo como: `$upload = __DIR__.'../assests/music';`

Comment: Hola!
gracias por tu respuesta, 
La carpeta en si esta en esta direccion public_html/assests/music, ahora voy a probar poniendo como me indicas vos con _DIR_

Comment: Recien probe de ambas formas $upload = __DIR__.'assests/music'; y __DIR__.'../assests/music'; y no esta funcionando en ninguna, assests esta dentro de public_html, que es donde esta el resto del codigo

Comment: Ojo si pusiste el `__DIR__` con doble subrayado es posible que falte el separador de directorios inmediatamente después fue un olvido mio. escribe así: `__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'assests/music'` no caí en cuenta en el comentario que hace falta el separador de directorios. **Disculpa**

Comment: si el archivo de código php se encuantra en algún directorio interior debes retroceder usando `__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../'` y `../` se repite una vez por cada nivel de retroceso necesario.

Comment: Probe poniendo como me dijiste vos con el __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../'  y sin ../ y todavia no esta subiendo los archivos.
La carpeta es: public_html/assests/music
Y el host es hostgator, no se si me faltara algun permiso o estoy tipiando algo mal?

Comment: No creo que le falten permisos. El problema está en la ubicación del archivo de script php. ¿Está en public_html?, ¿más abajo? (yo tengo un sitio en hostgator y ubico los scripts php fuera de public_html) o ¿a algún nivel dentro de public_html? indica ese dato en la pregunta para poder orientarte: muestra tu estructura de directorios indicando la posición desde la que se ejecuta el script

Comment: puse la foto que me pediste, mostrando donde estan todos los archivos, gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

quevedo Mi estructura de datos es la siguiente:
[image: Estructura parte 1]

[image: Parte 2]

El script esta dentro de public_html, y la carpeta que le quiero subir los archivos esta dentro de public_html assests.

Comment: De acuerdo con la imagen debo suponer que el archivo del script php en ejecución está en public_html de modo que para salvar la imagen debes hacer `$upload =__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'assests/music';` o `$upload = __DIR__.'/assests/music';` otra cosa será para crear las referencias de tipo `src="assests/music/imagenm.ext"` para mostrarla.

Comment: El script que sube la cancion esta dentro de uploadsong.php, que esta dentro de public html

Comment: Entonces la dirección para `$upload` que te indico en el comentario anterior es correcta. Para guardar debes hacer un condicional así: `if(move_uploaded_file($fileinfo['tmp_name'], $nuevopath)){ ... }else{ /* notificar error */ }` ojo $fileinfo enmascara lo recogido en $_FILES que haya pasado validaciones de tamaño, tipo mime, completez, tipos aceptados, etc. Y $nuevopath corresponde a `$upload.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nombre_a_asignar_con_ext` En tu código posiblemente falta el `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` en `$upload . $fileName`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Imagen 1]

Probe las 2 versiones de codigo que me recomendaste, intente subir este archivo:
[image: Archivo acargar]

Pero cuando voy a assests no lo veo al archivo
[image: carpeta]